# How can I get two items in a foreach loop in PHP?

Tags: php, foreach

I have a testimonial carousel. The carousel loop through two item each time. Now I want to get two items each time in a *foreach* loop. How can I get it?

**Code:**

```
<?php foreach ($kiyra_section_meta['testimonials-group'] as $single_testimonial): ?>
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="single-review">
                    <div class="media">
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h3 class="mt-0"><?php echo esc_html($single_testimonial['client-name']);   ?></h3>
                            <h5><?php echo esc_html($single_testimonial['client-position']);   ?></h5>
                            <i class="fas fa-quote-right fa-5x"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <?php echo esc_html($single_testimonial['client-testimonial']);   ?>

                </div> <!-- /.single-review -->
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Ah, I get it. You've got an array of testimonials, and you want to show 2 testimonials at the same time and then in the next slide 2 again, etc. I get it.

Comment: You could chunk your initial array, see array_chunk.

Comment: i used array_chunk, but i don't getting working

Comment: yes, @KIKOSoftware, you get right

Comment: You can also use `%` modules, but its trickier then array chunk in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use *[array_chunk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)* to split the array to group the two items, and then use *foreach* again:

```
foreach (array_chunk($input_array, 2) as $group) {
    // Start Group
    foreach ($group as $item) {
        // Item
    }
    // End group
}
```

Update with HTML

```
<div class="owl-carousel">
    <?php foreach (array_chunk($input_array, 2) as $group) : ?>
        <div class="owl-item">
            <?php foreach ($group as $item) : ?>
                <div class="item">
                    <!-- Code of item -->
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Php is so weird. Love it. Thank you. lol.